# Building a directed multigraph (Python)

Tags: python, dictionary, graph, hypercube

Lets say I get one list which represents the weights to adjacent nodes. The multigraph is shaped like a hypercube. The nodes will be named by their coordinates as a binary string.

En example for `n=3`

```
bin_string = ['000', '100', '010', '001', '110', '101', '011', '111']
weights = [[-5, -13, -2], [16, -9], [-15, 2], [13, -13], [18], [-9], [18]]
```

I want to build a dictionary from both lists in the following way: We start at `000` and have edges to all nodes with one 1 more in reversed lexicographic order (like in `bin_string`). The second node would be `100` (one 1 more, biggest first) and that node can have edges to all nodes with, again, one 1 more. So the dictionary would look like this:

```
d = { '000':{'100':-5, '010':-13, '001':-2},
      '100':{'110':16, '101':-9},
      '010':{'110':-15, '011':2},
      '001':{'101':13, '011':-13},
      '110':{'111':18},
      '101':{'111':-9},
      '011':{'111':18}
     }
```

I have hypercubes with all kinds of dimensions and can already generate `bin_string` depending on the dimension. But how do I marry `bin_string` and `weights` to one dictionary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python dictionaries have no defined order, so you'll need to use `collections.OrderedDict`. Here's an example:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

def one_more_one(s):
    for i, digit in enumerate(s):
        if digit == '0':
            yield s[:i] + '1' + s[i+1:]

bin_string = ['000', '100', '010', '001', '110', '101', '011', '111']
weights = [[-5, -13, -2], [16, -9], [-15, 2], [13, -13], [18], [-9], [18]]

d = OrderedDict()
for node, weight in zip(bin_string, weights):
    d[node] = OrderedDict(zip(one_more_one(node), weight))
```

Here, `one_more_one` is a generator yielding the neighbors of a node which have "one more one". It yields them in reverse lexicographic order.

If order isn't important, you can just use normal python dicts. You can recover a normal `dict` by writing:

```
{k:dict(v) for k,v in d.iteritems()}
```

which gives

```
{'000': {'001': -2, '010': -13, '100': -5},
 '001': {'011': -13, '101': 13},
 '010': {'011': 2, '110': -15},
 '011': {'111': 18},
 '100': {'101': -9, '110': 16},
 '101': {'111': -9},
 '110': {'111': 18}}
```

Comment: Why do you need `OrderedDict` exactly? At which point would your code break when using a normal dict instead?

Comment: @sebastian If I understood you correctly, you wanted the dictionary entries to be in reversed lexicographical order (e.g.: "edges to all nodes with one 1 more in reversed lexicographic order"). The problem is that the built-in python `dict` is not ordered, so this requirement cannot be satisfied. We therefore must used an `OrderedDict`, which *does* respect the order in which keys are added.